# Can I use each for elements create on the fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, each

Hello can I use each for elements that they are created on the fly?

```
$('#cart-info .shopp').each(function(){
    var cartitem = $(this);
    alert(cartitem);
    cartitem.find('img.remove').on('click',function(){
        alert(cartitem.attr('id'));
    });
});
```

I created elements under div cart-info. But unfortenately the click event does not work. If the elements are provided when the page loads it works. For example look at http://jsfiddle.net/epapathanasiou/jpdZt/1/

Comment: There are numerous examples of binding events for dynamic elements using event delegation in stack overflow. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: You should use `console.log()` rather than `alert()` for debugging - it is _much_ nicer to work with. Check your browser's JavaScript console for the output. You'll find that console within the Developer Tools of modern browsers, which are generally opened by pressing F12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#cart-info').on('click', '.shopp img.remove', function(){
    // this is the `img.remove` element
    alert($(this).closest('.shopp').attr('id'));
});
```

**[Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jpdZt/2/)**.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think you gave me a work around. In the beginning I tried to develop the solution as I did in the creation of the elements but unfortunately it did not work. Your code is very close to give a solution to my task.

Answer (score 1):

use event delegation

```
$('#cart-info').on('click', '.shopp img.remove', function(){
    alert(cartitem.attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: And now your `cartitem` is `undefined`. In the question it refers to the `.shopp` element.

Comment: I will use event delegation. Thank you very much. Your code I think it will not work because as i see it depends on iteration. But we cannot use each for elements are not created. I tried it and I did not get any events.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
$('#cart-info .shopp').each(function () {
    var cartitem = $(this);
    console.log(cartitem.text());
    cartitem.find('img').on('click',function () {
        console.log(cartitem.attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Comment: This is the same as the code in the question, except that you're no selecting all `img` elements inside each `.shopp`.

Comment: Unless in the actual code there are other images. And it doesn't solve the problem in the question

Comment: I will use event delegation. Thank you very much. Your code I think it will not work because as i see it depends on iteration. But we cannot use each for elements are not created. I tried it and I did not get any events

Comment: is up to you to decide what's answer fit with your problem, I don't know all possibilities.